# vs2008 and crystal report 2008 issue

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

We have installed Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition SP1, Microsoft .net  Framework  version  3.5 SP1 and crystal reports 2008 on our local machine.

While creating report in IDE (.net) we drag crystal report viewer from toolbox and bind crystal report to it. Now locally on our machine by default references for crystal report 10.5 gets  added to design page as Crystal Reports 10.5 comes bundled with Visual Studio 2008.  So we are not able to integrate crystal report 2008 to VS 2008.

This assembly reference is added automatically in our design page.

```
<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" 
namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>
```

while debugging vs2008  it will shows error, but without debugging if we change assembly like below it working fine.

```
<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>
```

any one can help me solve the issues

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 come with crystal report build in. the version (10.x)

and u have installed crystal report 2008. version (12.x)

the .net can only use 1 version. either 10.x or 12.x

once u decided the version, all the crystal dll have to reference to the version's dll u choosed.